# How to make the RecyclerView's ItemTouchHelper work on only part of the list(drag & drop)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, itemtouchhelper

I use RecyclerView's ItemTouchHelper to change the order(drag & drop),And I want to move only a part of the list.
I don't want to move after a certain index. How can I handle it with one RecyclerView?

If I explain a little more about what I want to make,
The active items are sorted up and the non-active items are sorted down. And only the activated items will shift the order.
Right now, when I drag an active item, it goes down to the area of ​​the non-active item, but I want to prevent it from going down. How can I do it?

UPDATE

```kotlin
open class SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback(private val mAdapter: ItemTouchHelperAdapter) :
    ItemTouchHelper.Callback() {

    private var isLongPressDrag = true

    fun setLongPressDragEnable(isLongPressDrag: Boolean) {
        this.isLongPressDrag = isLongPressDrag
    }

    override fun isLongPressDragEnabled() = isLongPressDrag

    override fun getMovementFlags(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    ): Int {
        val dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP or ItemTouchHelper.DOWN
        val swipeFlags = 0
        return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, swipeFlags)
    }

    override fun onMove(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    ): Boolean {
        return mAdapter.onItemMove(viewHolder.adapterPosition, target.adapterPosition)
    }

    override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, i: Int) {
        mAdapter.onItemDismiss(viewHolder.adapterPosition)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback) and override [`getDragDirs`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback#getDragDirs(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView,%20androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder)) and [`onMove`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ItemTouchHelper.Callback#onMove(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView,%20androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder,%20androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder)) methods:

```
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(
        UP or DOWN,
        0
) {
    override fun getDragDirs(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Int {
        val selectedPosition = viewHolder.adapterPosition
        val isActive: Boolean = // retrieve your model from list and check its active state
        return if (isActive) super.getDragDirs(recyclerView, viewHolder) else 0
    }
    override fun onMove(
            recyclerView: RecyclerView,
            viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
            target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
    ): Boolean {
        val toPosition = target.adapterPosition
        val isActiveTarget: Boolean = // retrieve your target model from list and check its active state
        if (!isActiveTarget) return false
        val fromPosition = viewHolder.adapterPosition
        moveItem(fromPosition, toPosition)
        return true
    }
}
```

Returning `0` on `getDragDirs` prevents inactive **item selection**, while returning `false` on `onMove` prevents item **movement while dragging**.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.
But I'm already using ItemtouchHelper.Callback. Should I create another class that uses SimpleCallback to use getDragDir?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, since `ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback` extends `ItemtouchHelper.Callback` itself internally you just need to use the simple callback to use its features like `getDragDirs` while having the callback primary functionality.

Comment: Is there any way to call getDragdir on simplecallback from existing callback? I want to keep things that I have customized..

Comment: `getDragDirs` is an open method declared in `ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback` however you can mimic its behavior by declaring one of your own and overriding `getMovementFlags` of `ItemtouchHelper.Callback` to call it and returning the right values. Update your question with your code so I can help you to implement it.

Comment: Thanks :) I added the code for itemTouchHelper.callback.
Since the callback is being used elsewhere, I want to add the getDragDir function to the callback without making a new callback. Please help.

Comment: Why don't you simply extend your own class from `ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback` instead of current `ItemtouchHelper.Callback` without making a new class from the begining?

Comment: I couldn't upload custom codes.. I only uploaded that part because I thought I could modify getMovementFlags. Other codes are modified like onChildDraw.

Comment: I changed only onMove based on your comment, but it is working as I want! I haven't edited getDragDirs, but I don't know why.. haha.
Thank you so much! Can I ask one more question..?
This RecyclerView is in nestedScrollView and when I try to move it to the bottom by dragging, I want to scroll down together..

Comment: Using nested scrolling containers (`RecyclerView` inside `NestedScrollView` or vice versa) while both scroll in the same direction is a bad idea unless you override their scrolling pattern (not your case I assume). Consider somehow blending them into one.